# Android -Programmatically Manipulate Button Position below ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I currently wanted to follow this layout but not sure how to control the buttons below. My problem is that the image stretched itself whatever the listview's width is. I wanted to follow the layout below. I am using Android's back button. [image]

[image]

I am not quite familiar in programmatically controlling the position of the image and it's default size. The button is inside `addFooterView(btnLoadMore);`

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_main_groups_activty, container, false);

            // Getting listview from xml
            ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            // Creating a button - Load More
            Button btnLoadMore = new Button(mContext);
            btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.navigation_back);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
            params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); 
            btnLoadMore.setLayoutParams(params2); 


            // Adding button to listview at footer
            lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

            return rootView;
}
```

**load_main_groups_activty**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"  
                android:background="@color/white"     
                >
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

            >
    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, You want that button to be footer view or to be list item?

Comment: The button is in the the footer view already. What I wanted is to programmatically put the button at the bottom left of the screen, without changing its original size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to implement this:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"    
                android:background="@color/white"     
                >
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
    </ListView>


         <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/navigation_back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am sure it'll help- you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To keep the image from stretching, you can create a `LinearLayout` and place the button inside it. By setting the `gravity` attribute, you can position the button in the center, left or right of the `ListView` footer. After adding the button to the `LinearLayout`, the `LinearLayout` can be added to `ListView` footer.

See if the following code gets you the layout you want:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_main_groups_activty, container, false);

        // Getting listview from xml
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Creating a button - Load More
        Button btnLoadMore = new Button(mContext);
        btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.navigation_back);

        LinearLayout llFooter = new LinearLayout(mContext);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsBtn = new 
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
        paramsBtn.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        llFooter.addView(btnLoadMore, paramsBtn);   

        //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new 
              //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                     //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  

        //llFooter.setLayoutParams(params2);

        // Adding button to listview at footer
        lv.addFooterView(llFooter);

        return rootView;
```

}

Comment: Getting, errors with your code. I also inflated the load_main_groups_activty.xml Logcat errors: http://pastie.org/8166210

Comment: Ok, updated the code. Let's try without the `LayoutParams` set.